# Netlogo: how to create a network of turtles sharing the same feature in a random way?

Tags: random, netlogo, social-networking

I know how to create a network of turtles sharing the same feature (sds)

```
  ask turtlel[              
     create-links-with other turtles with [
sds = [ sds ] of myself ]
```

My question is, it is possible to link just some of those? For example, a link is created given a random probability from zero to one between to turtles having the same sds

Answer (score 1):

You need the primitive `n-of`. Try something like this (you could code in fewer lines, but I have stretched it out for readability:

```
let target-prop 0.2
ask turtles
[ let samesds other turtles with [sds = [sds] of myself]
  let join-count ceiling target-prop * count samesds
  if any? samesds
  [ create-links-with n-of join-count samesds
  ]
]
```

Now that you have done a little bit of exploring with NetLogo, you might want to have another go at the tutorials and also look at the library models to get a feel for some of the primitives that are available.